# RegExp in JavaScript: include one Unicode group and exclude another one

Tags: javascript, regex, web, unicode

I have to write some regexp. And I know where is a lot of variants. But I find the thing that I don't understand, so I want to ask.

I had this regexp:
`` /^[\p{Letter} \-'`’–]+$/u ``
It has to allow Latin and symbols like Ü, Æ ect.

And it has bug - it allows also Ukrainian (Cyrillic) symbols "і Ї".
So I want to add the rule "exclude Cyrillic". But I don't know how to do it.

I tried `` /^[\p{Letter} \-'`’–][^\p{sc=Cyrillic}]+$/u; `` but the last part [^] means all except Cyrillic ((

Please, don't say me to rewrite regexp. I just want to learn how can I write "exclude" rule.

Thanks)

Comment: I am not sure but I think you cannot do it in one go ("match all the letters _but_ the Cyrillic ones"); would it be possible for you to split the check in two separate steps (first match all letters, then exclude Cyrillic from the resulting match)?

Comment: @secan Yes, I can. But maybe here is such possibility) Who knows

Comment: [Character Class Subtraction](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) is not an universal feature of regular expressions.

Comment: @ceving
[\p{IsThai}-[^\p{Nd}]] I had error 'Dangling metacharacter' in the ']]'
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @illia_6655321 Did you read the linked text? Do not think so: *Character class subtraction is supported by the XML Schema, XPath, .NET (version 2.0 and later), and JGsoft regex flavors.* Does this mean, that it is supported by JavaScript?

Comment: @ceving Yes. About Unicode Scripts I read the same. But sc= solve the problem. So I just asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `` /^[\p{Letter} \-'`’–]+$/u `` regex, `\p{Letter}` matches any letter in the Unicode table. However, `\p{Alphabetic}` includes more letters, and you would like to use this Unicode category class if you planned to match any Unicode letter.

Since you only want to match Latin letters you should replace `\p{Letter}` with `\p{sc=Latin}` or `\p{sc=Latn}` (note the hyphen should be just used at the end of the character class, it is the cleanest way to use it here).

Note that the `sc=`, or `Script=` (this is for Script names,  `scx=` or `Script_Extensions=` can be used for script extensions) prefix is required to work with those script names in Unicode category classes (see [ECMAScript reference](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-unicodematchproperty-p)).

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const rx = /^[\p{sc=Latn} '`’–-]+$/u;
console.log( rx.test("Вася-Пупкин’о") ); // => false
console.log( rx.test("Łukasz Ąłski") );  // => true
console.log( rx.test("Chloé Alméras") ); // => true
```

If you wanted to match any letters **but** Cyrillic ones, you would need to only add a negative lookahead like this:

```js
const rx = /^(?:(?!\p{sc=Cyrl})[\p{Alphabetic} '`’–-])+$/u;
console.log( rx.test("Вася-Пупкин’о") ); // => false
console.log( rx.test("עֲדִינָה") );         // => true
console.log( rx.test("Łukasz Ąłski") );  // => true
console.log( rx.test("Chloé Alméras") ); // => true
```

See more about [value aliases and canonical values for the Unicode properties (Script and Script_Extensions) here](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#table-unicode-script-values).

Comment: Thanks! You've helped me a lot. Amazing and clear answer